# gethostbyaddr on Ubuntu 64

Tags: c, ubuntu, autotools

running the configure script for mozart oz gives me this:

`checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes

checking for gethostbyaddr in -lnsl... no

checking for gethostbyaddr in -lc... no

checking for gethostbyaddr... no

configure: error: Function gethostbyaddr is not available.

The system cannot be built.`

configure: error: /home/stewart/dev/mozart/mozart/platform/emulator/configure failed for emulator
configure: error: /home/stewart/dev/mozart/mozart/platform/configure failed for platform

how do I get gethostbyaddr on my latest ubuntu 64 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a

sudo apt-get install tk-dev tcl-dev build-essential libc6-dev g++-multilib ia32-libs lib32z1-dev lib32gmp3-dev

this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyaddr` is in the C library, which must be installed for a working Ubuntu system. There's probably a bug in the `configure` script.

I don't know why the `configure` script fails, but you may want to remove all lines referencing `gethostbyaddr` from `mozart/platform/emulator/configure.in`, followed by an `autoreconf`.

Comment: what is the best way to test if it is actually there?
I suppose it wouldnt work otherwise -- thanks

Comment: @Setori: Updated my post with easier installation instructions.

Comment: not possible, as I want to work on the code base. Also I dont think mozart is in the 64 bit package repo. I recall this being the case.

Comment: @Setori: updated again. Are you working from the SVN? Apparently they updated it to make Linux/x64 builds easier.

Comment: there is an effort atm to move house to http://github.com/mozart this will be the canonical mozart once the list is happy. Thanks for that tip shall do as you say.